# XRDP (in a WSL distro) not connecting to remote desktop

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, batch, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I was making a Batch file. By using it, I open a program in command line (WSL, to be specific). The program takes in some input. For an specific example-
i'm making a Batch file which runs `wsl --distribution kali-linux` and then automatically runs `sudo service xrdp start` on that virtual machine so that i could connect to its desktop. but When the batch file runs kali-linux the cmd does:

```
┌──(user㉿DESKTOP-6SNGSF1)-[/mnt/c/Users/Saaransh Garg]
└─$
```

I want to know how can I give the `sudo service xrdp start` command to the VM? I think this would be similar to giving input to a program.

Also, I have tried doing like: `wsl -- sudo service xrdp start` but, when i try to connect to VM, it shows "an internal error had occured". I'm considering, as WSL is still in development, that this is just a bug. So i have no other option but to give input to the WSL  throught .bat file

As for the setup, I configured Kali in [NetworkChuck's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfVH54edAHU) way, following up by [this David Bombal's](https://youtu.be/IL7Jd9rjgrM?t=530) video to change port to 3390. In short what I did was this-

1. Install kali from microsoft store, update and upgrage kali, install xfce and XRDP
2. Following David Bombal in the video mentioned from 8:50 and using the commands mentioned [here](https://github.com/davidbombal/wsl2/blob/main/ubuntu_gui_youtube) to change port to 3390

What I wanted from all this was to make a batch file such that whenever i run that, Kali linux gets connected to RD. My attempt:-

```
wsl --user root --distribution kali-linux --exec sh -c "service xrdp start"
mstsc /v:localhost:3390 /g:RDP
```

Note:

1. I'm using WSL v2

Comment: WSL1 or WSL2?  At least for me, I use WSL1 and need no such thing.  I use ***x11 forwarding*** and VcXsrv to launch x11 apps.  I would suggest that if you are using WSL for a complete desktop experience (as opposed to windows/linux interoperability) that you might be happier with a complete VM (like VirtualBox).  You are essentially trying to run a remote Linux desktop locally via xrdp.  X11 isn't designed this way and things like VNC and xrdp are inherently "add ons".  I know I didn't answer your Q but thought you might be happier knowing another way.

Comment: I know i can use virtual box for VMs, but actually i have a low-end PC. When i compared the performance of VirtualBox and WSL, i liked the performance of WSL. Therefore I'm currently running my VM on WSL

Comment: Also, I know that xrdp is just a workaround until microsoft provides desktop experience in WSL, but still, xrdp had never troubled me before, so i continue to do it that way

Comment: AWESOME! .. I get it ;)  ..  What I am telling you is that you probably don't need xrdp and if your problem is performance, x11 forwarding is the guy to use. :)  It takes WAY LESS resources than xrdp and runs MUCH FASTER.  The "Linux side" needs a variable set called DISPLAY as in `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0` (learn about the 0:0 part later).  The "Windows side" needs an xserver like VcXsrv running (very low resource usage).  Then from bash, you can simply run things and they will popup in windows.. like `$ xterm&` and boom!  Worth the time to figure it out..

Comment: Sir can you please elaborate the steps in an answer. If possible, please also tell, how can we do all the connecting process automatically, using a bat file or some other thing?

Comment: ***The answer from @NotTheDr01ds below is exactly what you asked for.***  I myself wouldn't use xrdp but that is a matter of preference.  Search the web for `x11 forwarding wsl` and you will find many hits.  BTW, x11 forwarding is no different between WSL or a REAL Linux instance.   How to do the connecting like what you were trying to do before? .. YOU DON'T .. it's already running.  You just open a bash prompt and fire up any x11 app you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `xrdp` specifically, try:

```
wsl ~ -u root -e sh -c "nohup service xrdp start"
```

While a `wsl -u root -e sh -c "command"` will work for most commands (and even most services), the `init.d` script for `xrdp` seems to have an issue with this.  I believe this is due to a timing issue, where the shell (the owning process) terminates before `xrdp` gets a chance to fork.  `nohup` just makes sure that the full `xrdp` init script gets a chance to run before that happens.

This really isn't a WSL issue -- The same thing can be seen if you were do something similar with `exec sh -c "sudo service xrdp start"`.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This answers the question as originally asked -- How to pass input to the WSL command.  However, the question was subsequently edited to add this answer to the question and raise a new issue.  Leaving it here for historical purposes.*

Try something along the lines of:

```
wsl --user root --distribution kali-linux --exec sh -c "service xrdp start" # long form options
wsl -u root -d kali-linux -e sh -c "service xrdp start" # short form
```

That should work.  It runs the distro as root (to avoid the use of a password on `sudo`), and execs the `sh` (for fastest execution time and avoidance of any of your normal shell's startup scripts) with a commandline of `service xrdp start`.

You might also consider:

```
wsl -u root -d kali-linux -e sh -c "service xrdp status || service xrdp start"
```

Which will first check to see if it's running before starting it.

Alternative invocation from CMD:

```
echo service xrdp start | wsl -u root -d kali-linux -e sh
```

But quoting rules start to get much more hairy, IMHO.

Comment: I used (almost) the same command. Still i checked these. These still doesn't work

Comment: Try something more basic then, and build up to the more complicated version to see when/where it breaks -- For instance, does `wsl -u root -d kali -e sh -c "echo Hello"` work?

Comment: Yess!! It prints hello like it must have.

Comment: File operations also work - checked with `wsl -u root -e sh -c "touch /home/user1/Desktop/file1.txt"` command

Comment: Then I try using this command - `wsl -u root -e sh -c "sudo service xrdp start"`. It prints the normal expected output - `Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server: xrdp-sesman xrdp.`. But connecting it through Remote Desktop connection fails. I tried connecting using both `localhost:3390` and also IP address of the VM. Both fails

Comment: @saaranshgarg Are you saying that if you start `xrdp` from within WSL, you can connect to it via Remote Desktop, but if you start it this way, it doesn't?  Can you confirm that you can still connect via Remote Desktop at all?

Comment: Yes, you got my issue, if i run `wsl` and then run xrdp it would do the expected, but this is not the case while using the `wsl {command]` or any similar format

Comment: Ok, so things to check there.  First do the `wsl ...` command to start `xrdp`, then (pretty much immediately) follow that up by starting the instance with a shell.  Check the `sudo service xrdp status` from within the instance.  Then try to connect.  Any difference?  It's *possible* that WSL is terminating the instance since there's no shell running, but it shouldn't since the `xrdp` daemon running should be enough to keep it from terminating.  Also, do you have more than one instance?  I know in the original example you mentioned passing it the `--distribution` parameter.

Comment: Ok, so i checked what you said to, and it tells me that session manager (`xrdp-sesman`) is running. However it says that `xrdp` is not running (i know that it only runs once you connect to remote desktop)

Comment: And i passed the `--distribution` flag just for clarity, I am currently having only one distro, that is Kali Linux

Comment: Hey, @NotTheDr01ds is it possible that when we give `wsl [command]`, windows try to convert the linux commands into native windows commands, which causes problems?

Comment: @saaranshgarg Shouldn't be.  That's the reason for passing it with `-e sh "command"`  It removes the ambiguity (other than any characters that may need to be quoted/escaped from PowerShell, which isn't the case here).

Comment: So, @NotTheDr01ds, what do I do now?

Comment: @saaranshgarg I'm going to try to set this up to see if I can find any other suggestions.  Might take me a few days, though.  Any other information you can provide on how you set it up originally might help.  Probably best to put that in an edit to your original question.

Comment: Ok, @NotTheDr01ds, I will actually reform the question focusing on this problem rather than focusing on the batch file

Comment: @saaranshgarg Really, you should revert that edit and put your "connection issue" in a new question.  Otherwise this current answer, and all of the current comments on both the question and answer just don't make sense.  That's one of the reasons that the editing rules prevent us from changing the core *meaning* of a question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128412/discussion-between-saaransh-garg-and-notthedr01ds).